# How do I query a single data value from the wp_metadata table?

Tags: php, templates, search

I am modifying a search.php template. The basic template displays search results with thumbnail, title, date, and author. I would like to add 2 additional fields from the wp_metadata table. I assume I need to write a function and add it to my child theme functions.php file, then call the function from the template. I just need to know how to correctly write the function.

Comment: wp_metadata ?? I think you are talking about wp_postmeta table

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I meant to say wp_postmeta. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/):

> **get_post_meta( $post_id, $key = '', $single = false )**
>
> Retrieve post meta field for a post
>
> **$post_id** (int) (Required) Post ID.
>
> **$key** (string) (Optional) The meta key to retrieve. By default, returns data for all keys. Default value: ''
>
> **$single** (bool) (Optional) Whether to return a single value. Default value: false

eg.

```
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'the-name-of-key', true);
```

When using `true`, you will get a `string`, but if you use `false` instead, you will get an `array`.

Comment: Thanks J....small syntax errors on my part. I was thaaaaat close.

Comment: Glad I could help. If that's what you needed, dont forget to tick it as the correct answer.